# How to protect againt typos when setting value for class members?

Tags: python

Consider the following example:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.veryImportantSession = 1

a = A()
a.veryImportantSession = None # ok

# 200 lines below
a.veryImportantSessssionnnn = 2 # I wanna exception here!! It is typo!
```

How could I make it so that an exception will be raised if I try to set a member that is not set in `__init__`?

Code above won't fail when it is executed, but gives me a fun time to debug the problems.

Like with str:

```
>>> s = "lol"
>>> s.a = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might get better answers if you also explain why you want to do this.

Comment: Attempts to turn Python into Java/C++ have always perplexed me in the same way the Singleton anti-pattern does. If you don't want more than one Foo, don't instantiate it, if you don't want `a.y` don't bind it. If you want to constrain your library user in mysterious ways, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: ok, probably that is not what I really want to to. The problem is that objects of A class are used in many places of code, and member "a" has hight importance. Let's say that it's real name is "superImportantSession". In case of I made typo in one place of code and wrote "a.superImportantSesssssion = 1", I wont get any error when that code line will be executed. But I will have fun time to debug the error.

Probably I have to use setSession / getSession or smth like that.

Comment: In all my time using Python, I've never once had a hard-to-debug problem as a result of an attribute name typo.  This is a make-believe problem: people used to other languages think it's a huge problem, but it's really not.

Comment: Having suffered from this issue, let me assure you it is *not* make-believe.  For me, the trick was to select one naming convention, *remember* my choice, and stick with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could override [__setattr__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) to only allow attribute names from a defined list.

```
class A(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        allowed = ('x',)
        if name in allowed:
            self.__dict__[name]  = value
        else:
            raise AttributeError('No attribute: %s' % name)
```

In operation:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.x = 5
>>> a.other = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "myc.py", line 7, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError('No attribute: %s' % name)
AttributeError: No attribute: other
```

However, as [msw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282912/msw) has commented, attempts to make Python behave more like Java or C++ are usually a bad idea and will lead to losing lots of the benefits that Python provides. If you are concerned about making typos that might be missed then you are much better spending time writing unit tests for your code than trying to lock down the usage of your classes.

Comment: Agreed w/ unit tests, but is it really best way to avoid typos?

Comment: A combination of unit tests and other kinds of automated tests. e.g. using your example from the comments on the question itself, if there was a test that checked the state of your session before and after an operation you would be able to tell if `superImportantSession` had not been set correctly.

Comment: @Stipa: I'd say so, as You would have to do two same typos. Something like typo during both variable declaration and setter.

Comment: There are lots of cases where it's very useful for user code to be able to assign arbitrary attributes to classes, without the class itself caring about them.  This would break that for no reason.  Also remember that this will only catch anything at runtime, not compile-time.  Don't do this unless you have a specific reason to.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a class variable called `__slots__`. See the [Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) for more information.

`__slots__` only work in new-style classes, so you need `class A(object)` instead of `class A` in this example.

```
class A(object):
    __slots__ = ['x']
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

>>> a = A()
>>> a.x = 2
>>> a.y = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Comment: `__slots__` is for memory optimization and should very rarely be used.  Using it to "protect against typos" is misusing it--please don't recommend it for this purpose.  Novices won't understand what they're breaking--for example, this silently broke weakrefs.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to protect against typos is to use a tool such as [pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) or [pylint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint) -- these will go through your code and let you know if you have a variable `a.superImportantSesssssionnnn` that is not ever used again, as well as many other things.

If you insist on doing it in code you have two options:

- (ab)use `__slots__` -- the primary purpose of `__slots__` is memory optimization for those times when you will have hundreds, thousands, or millions of objects and you need to keep your objects' footprints as small as possible.  If you go this route you should make sure and include `__weakref__` as one of the allowed names so [weak references](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html) will continue to work.
- (ab)use `__setattr__` -- the primary purpose of `__setattr__` is to allow code to be run to validate, manipulate, or otherwise take the data given and put it in the correct format for storage

To reiterate, the above two options are not intended to be used as spell-checkers, and your efforts to limit the usefulness of your code by disallowing every possible attribute name except for those few you use yourself may not be appreciated when someone is trying to support a use-case you did not anticipate.