# Python: Can a class forbid clients setting new attributes?

Tags: python, oop, typing

I just spent too long on a bug like the following:

```
>>> class Odp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "bar"


>>> o = Odp()
>>> o.raw_foo = 3 # oops - meant o.foo
```

I have a class with an attribute. I was trying to set it, and wondering why it had no effect. Then, I went back to the original class definition, and saw that the attribute was named something slightly different. Thus, I was creating/setting a new attribute instead of the one meant to.

First off, isn't this exactly the type of error that statically-typed languages are supposed to prevent? In this case, what is the advantage of dynamic typing?

Secondly, is there a way I could have forbidden this when defining `Odp`, and thus saved myself the trouble?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079306/how-to-protect-againt-typos-when-setting-value-for-class-members

Answer (score 22):

You can implement a `__setattr__` method for the purpose -- that's much more robust than the `__slots__` which is often misused for the purpose (for example, `__slots__` is automatically "lost" when the class is inherited from, while `__setattr__` survives unless explicitly overridden).

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
  if hasattr(self, name):
    object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  else:
    raise TypeError('Cannot set name %r on object of type %s' % (
                    name, self.__class__.__name__))
```

You'll have to make sure the `hasattr` succeeds for the names you *do* want to be able to set, for example by setting the attributes at a class level or by using `object.__setattr__` in your `__init__` method rather than direct attribute assignment.  (To forbid setting attributes on a **class** rather than its **instances** you'll have to define a custom metaclass with a similar special method).

Comment: why did you choose `TypeError`? Maybe wrongfully, I had `AttributeError` in mind.

Comment: "does not support XX assignment" messages (e.g for items) use `TypeError`, more confusingly worded "has no attribute XX" ones use `AttributeError`, so I guess either is OK (though neither quite perfect).